# Different function definition after compilation

Tags: dll, static, c++-cli

I have my Keyboard class:

```
namespace BSGameFramework
{
namespace Input
{
    static public ref class Keyboard
    {
        public:

            static KeyboardState GetState();
    };
}
}
```

Where KeyboardState is a ref struct.

After compilation as dll from my C# application I see the function from metadata as follow:

```
namespace BSGameFramework.Input
{
public class Keyboard
{
    public Keyboard();

    public static void GetState(ref KeyboardState value);
}
}
```

Keyboard class has lost its static state and the function GetState is now returning void and taking a KeyboardState as referenced parameter!

Somebody know why? Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because of the return type, `ref struct KeyboardState`.

In C++/CLI, the "ref" vs. "value" is the thing that determines whether a type is a reference type or a value type, not "class" vs. "struct". `ref class` and `ref struct` are both the same thing as C#'s `class`. `value class` and `value struct` are both the same thing as C#'s `struct`.

Therefore, you have a C++/CLI method declared as returning a reference type, but without the `^`. This data type does exist in C++/CLI, but not in C#. The method signature you see is a workaround.

There are two possible solutions to this issue:

- Change `KeyboardState` to a `value struct`. From what you said, it sounds like you intended for this to be a value type from the beginning, so this is probably the best solution.
- Change the return type of the method to `KeyboardState^`. This will let the method show up in C# the same as it does in C++/CLI. However, if you do this, you'll want to switch all uses of `KeyboardState` to `KeyboardState^`. It's a reference type, it should be used with a `^`.

Comment: I've changed ref struct to value struct and now is all working fine, thank a lot :D

Comment: I've noticed that Keyboard is always not static, do you know why?